# How can i add items to DataGrid when users scroll to the bottom?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollview

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgMain" 
              Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

the ItemsSource binding to `public ObservableCollection<Student> Items { get; set; }`

the items i well init with

```
       Items = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new Student() { Id = i, Name = "name" + i.ToString() });
        }
```

how can i make the dataGrid first show 50 items and when the user scroll to the bottom i well loaded other 50 items and then.

1.there is don't have scroll to bottom event in scrollView so how can i get the scroll to bottom ?

2.how can i make the dataGrid show 50 items when the itemsSource have 1000 items ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in paging so if you want 50 items you need to only have 50 items in the source.

DataGrid supports virtualization.  Why not just constrain the height?   Height="200".